# Ordenar valores array php!

Tags: php, json

Tenho um retorno *JSON*.

```
"members": [
        {
            "name": "Drogo",
            "role": 3,
            "donations": 278,
```

Onde uso o `foreach` para percorre-lo!

```
foreach ( $CMAMBERS as $e )
    {
       echo "nome: $e->name<br>";
    }
```

Preciso ordenar o valor que eu recebo em ordem decrescente, não de acordo com o `$e->name`, mas sim o `$e->donations` então eu preciso exibir os nomes em ordem decrescente de acordo com o array `donations`

Então se eu tiver os seguintes valores:

```
"Name": "Drogo"
"donations": "150"

"Name": "FoX"
"donations": "350"

"Name": "TRE"
"donations": "250"
```

Eu deva imprimir assim:

```
"FoX"
"TRE"
"Drogo"
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um dos métodos [usort](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php) e [uasort](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uasort.php), ambos funcionam da mesma maneira, recebe o `array` e uma função de comparação.

```
$dados = [
  [
    'nome' => 'Drogo',
    'donations' => 150
  ],
  [
    'nome' => 'FoX',
    'donations' => 350
  ],
  [
    'nome' => 'TRE',
    'donations' => 250
  ]
];

uasort($dados, function ($a, $b) {
  return $a['donations'] < $b['donations'];
});

foreach ( $dados as $e )
{
  echo "nome: " . $e['nome'] . "\n";
}
```

> Veja funcionando [uasort](https://repl.it/repls/CommonIncompatibleQuagga) e [usort](https://repl.it/repls/ViciousScaryTermite)

#### Referência

- [Ordenando Arrays](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/array.sorting.php)

Comment: Creio que não seja possível usar dentro do foreach, preciso usar dentro dele!

Comment: Faz a ordenação antes do `foreach`. Atualizei a resposta e os exemplos funcionando.

Comment: AH, sim claro... Obrigado!